# Set a default format for a phone number

Tags: excel, formatting, excel-formula, cells

Can I set the default format for phone number?

I know the Format Cells feature of MS Excel will format the number, but I have extensive custom requirements.

If the user enters the phone number **+1 923-456-7890** then it should automatically format the number by **removing extra spaces**, **special characters** and the **country code**.

The new format should be **(923) 456-7890**.

If any help is there, it is highly appreciated.

Comment: well, you can use this format : "[<=9999999] ###-####;(###) ###-####" ... however, it doesn't handle that country code very well ... note that I don't think you'll be able to get Excel to "format" it, you'll probably need a formula in a 2nd column.

Answer (score 0):

A single example is not a good general guide but please try:

```
="("&SUBSTITUTE(CLEAN(TRIM(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1),LEN(A1)))),"-",")",1)
```